Angular: inlineCritical optimization set to false does not remove inline styles (required for strict CSP)
I am working on an Angular 14 project where I need to comply with a strict Content Security Policy (CSP) that includes the directive "style-src 'self'". This means I cannot have any inline-styles in my application.
How can I completely remove inline styles to ensure that I can use style src 'self' in my CSP? Is there any additional configuration or workaround needed to prevent Angular from inlining styles?
I cannot use ngCspNonce here as it is not supported in Angular version 14.
I tried setting the 'inlineCritical' option to 'false' in the angular.json file under the build configurations, expecting it to remove the inline styles.
       "build": {
          "configurations": {
              "optimization": {
                "scripts": true,
                "styles": {
                  "minify": true,
                  "inlineCritical": false
                }
              },
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
           }
        }

Console errors
